# Looking for this spade connector and KiCAD model

Tags: pcb, connector, kicad

[image: Spade Connector]

I am looking for this part but with single male to female connector, KiCAD PCB module and 3D model. I am struggling to find the part name, at the least.

I appreciate every bit of help!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, these are [FASTON terminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTON_terminal) also known as "quick disconnect", "tab" terminals, or blade connectors. Here they are on [mouser](http://www.mouser.com/TE-Connectivity/Connectors/Terminals/187-FASTON-Series/_/N-5g5u?P=1ywwwf5Z1yzs6iiZ1yroslp), [farnell](http://uk.farnell.com/c/connectors/crimp-terminals-solder-terminals-splices/quick-disconnect-crimp-terminals?terminal-type=quick-disconnect-adapter)

Comment: Those are not intended to mount on a PC board, so I wouldn't expect to find KiCAD models or footprints for them.  They are designed to push onto a single "Faston(tm)" tab to permit two female connectors to attach to a single male tab.

Comment: Soon or later, you must learn to create your own parts, I also used to scrounge the net for footprint parts I needed, but now I always create my own parts. If you have the 3D file in STEP format you can use KiCAD StepUp plugin for FreeCAD and generate wrl files so its displayed in kicad 3D viewer.